# href not working in type="application/rss+xml"

Tags: rss-reader

I am trying to navigate the url with the help of RSS feed in modern browser. Some of the url not navigating . i am getting below error:

DTD is prohibited.
 Line: 1 Character: 11

I have used below code to navigate the url:

```
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Latest News" href="https://www.xxx.xxx" />. Kindly help me out from this.
```

Comment: Does the error occur when the page containing this <link> tag is rendered, or when the https://www.xxx.xxx href is about to be rendered? At any rate, I am quite certain that your code is not line 1.

Comment: error occured when the url is about to be rendered. i am facing this with particular href only.